# What is NetBSD's FIONSPACE ioctl equivalent in Linux?

Tags: linux, sockets, ioctl, netbsd

I'm using Linux 2.6.38 (fc14). What is the ioctl flag to get the amount of free space on a socket file descriptor (say, a TCP socket)? I found NetBSD has FIONREAD, FIONWRITE and FIONSPACE for such related purposes. But, I could only use FIONREAD in Linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`SIOCOUTQ` is the Linux equivalent of `FIONWRITE`.  I don't believe there is a direct `FIONSPACE` equivalent: instead, you can subtract the value returned by `SIOCOUTQ` from the socket send buffer size, which can be obtained with `getsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, ...)`.

Comment: Please note that there is no guarantee that write operations do not block even if there is room in the socket send buffer according to this calculation. In practice with kernel 3.2.0 I sometimes get EWOULDBLOCK on send() even with ample space in the send buffer.

Answer (score 0):

For information, about what @HKK says, found in man socket(7):

> SO_SNDBUF
>
> Sets or  gets  the maximum socket send buffer in bytes. The
> kernel doubles this value (to allow space for bookkeeping overhead)
> when it is set using setsockopt(2), and **this doubled  value  is
> returned**  by getsockopt(2).   The  default  value is set by the
> /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default file and the maximum allowed value is
> set by the /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max file.  The minimum (doubled)
> value for this option is 2048.